# Referer spoof via built-in modules

Tags: javascript, node.js, http-referer, spoofing

I've been wondered if there's way to spoof Referer on request using built-in expressions only,
(no external modules like request.js, ajax or so)
XMLHttpRequest throws error upon attempt to change unsafe headers, including Referer.
is there a way I could make this work?
reason why I dislike using external is, they often have features I won't ever use and thus most likely heavy.
been using request.js but after webpack analyze I decided not to due to its size.

Comment: Are you asking about node.js `http` module, or a clientside `XMLHttpRequest`/`fetch`? There are no restrictions on setting any headers using [`http.request`](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_request_options_callback).

Comment: @Bergi thanks that solved me an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Browsers are, as you've discovered, hard-nosed about letting your in-page Javascript change security-related headers when you make [XHR](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) or [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API) requests. The prominent browsers won't let your Javascript do it. Why not?  Cybercreeps can infest in-page Javascript with malware.  It doesn't matter whether you use any sort of in-page framework like jQuery, or not. You can't change those headers.

nodejs programs let you do whatever you want with headers.